# How do I automatically install packages with commands in a python file?

Tags: python, pip, package

I'm planning to distribute my python program to a few users, however, I've manually installed some of the packages that come in the program as they weren't installed in my version.

I'd rather my users have the packages pre-installed rather than forcing them to manually install it, as it can be very complex for users who have never used python. How would I run a command that installs packages such as requests, os etc..

Here's a rough sketch:

```
try:
    import os
except:
    os = 'pip install os'
    subprocess.call(os, shell=os)
```

It seems unpythonic to continue using this for every package, so I was wondering if there was a way to check every package that's being used in the program so I could have them all installed in the main.py file

Comment: `os` is a builtin module. Are you try to install that? or just an example?

Comment: why don't you try to use virtual environments? i think thats a better approach

Comment: @BlackThunder they're just examples, I know its builtin

Comment: @carlosza If you mean like repl, I'd rather not as my targeted users are not experienced with any programming. It'd just be haywire

Comment: You can download the module file and keep it with the py file. If the module import fails then install it from the directory. I used this concept in one of my program: https://github.com/BlackThunder01001/cx_freeze_GUI . You can try that method. (Its open source)